# Ensure that an image is displayed on browser

Tags: gwt, gwt2

How to be sure that an image is displayed on browser before further action?

I want to load some images in certain sequence because i want to be sure that an image will be always as background. I write the following code:

```
// load the view
final IView bgView = new StaticImgView(Constants.BG_CLASS, "Background", bgPath);
this.dPanel.add(bgView);
bgView.addErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onError(ErrorEvent event) {

        GWT.log("No Background-View.");
        loadLogoView();

    }

});
bgView.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {

        GWT.log("Background-View loaded.");
        GWT.log("> " + TicketViewer.this.dPanel.getWidgetCount());
        loadLogoView();

    }

});
```

But the 'Logo' image is not displayed upon the background..(?).

- bgView extends Image.
- loadLogoView contains similar code to load another image.
- Note that the background image is 800x600, while all the other images are smaller 104x100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `LoadHandler` to the image (`Image.addLoadHandler(LoadHandler)`).

Comment: This was my approach also, but for some reason it does not work! When the first image is loaded into an AbsolutePanel, i get its WidgetIndex=1, and then at loadLogoView, i get the logo WidgetIndex=2, but logo does not appear!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what constitutes further action.  A general purpose scenario is if you are using JQuery, you can do this:

```
$('#imageId').load(function() { //Do Something })
```

Where imageId corresponds to the id in your img tag.

```
<img src="test.jpg" id="imageId" />
```